# Generic collections type test

Tags: c#, types, generic-collections

I'd like to make some operations according to a given collection type (using reflexion), regardless of the generic type.

Here is my code:

```
    void MyFct(Type a_type)
    {
        // Check if it's type of List<>
        if (a_type.Name == "List`1")
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        // Check if it's type of Dictionary<,>
        else if (a_type.Name == "Dictionary`2")
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

It works for now, but it gets obvious to me that it's not the most safe solution.

```
    void MyFct(Type a_type)
    {
        // Check if it's type of List<>
        if (a_type == typeof(List<>))
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        // Check if it's type of Dictionary<,>
        else if (a_type == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

I tried that too, it actualy compiles but doesn't work...
I also tried to test all interfaces of the given collection type, but it implies an exclusivity for interfaces in collections...

I hope I made myself clear, my english lack of training :)

Comment: do `a_type.ToString().` what does it say?

Comment: I suspect you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Adding type-specific checks to generic code is smelly.

Comment: * a_type.ToString() => System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]

Comment: @s0ubap: That certainly explains why the test against "List`1" failed

Comment: hum.. It actually works; a_type.Name is actually "List`1". I'm just wondering if it's the only solution, which seems "smelly" to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to see if something implements a specific generic type, then you would need to do this:

```
if(a_type.IsGenericType && a_type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
```

The `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` method will return the unbounded generic type for you test against.