# Check whether an object is ObservableCollection or not?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to check whether a value is of type ObservableCollection of any type ,or not in C# ?

eg: I can check whether a value is of string type or not as follows :

```
string value = "value to Check";
bool b = value.GetType().Equals(typeof(string));  // b =true
```

but If I need to check whether a value is ObservableCollection or not , irrespective of the constituent type , how can I do this ?

eg:

```
ObservableCollection<T> collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
```

If I am checking like this

```
bool b = collection.GetType().Equals(typeof(ObservableCollection<>)); // b=false
```

How can I check whether the value is collection or not ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic collections type test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355635/generic-collections-type-test)

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
bool b = collection.GetType().IsGenericType &&
           collection.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check it like so:

```
public static bool IsObservableCollection(object candidate) {
    if (null == candidate) return false;

    var theType = candidate.GetType();
    bool itIs = theType.IsGenericType() && 
        !theType.IsGenericTypeDefinition()) &&
        (theType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>));

    return itIs;
}
```

You can also get the element type:

```
public static Type GetObservableCollectionElement(object candidate) {
    bool isObservableCollection = IsObservableCollection(candidate);
    if (!isObservableCollection) return null;

    var elementType = candidate.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    return elementType;
}
```

**EDIT**

Actually using the ObservableCollection in a dynamic manner is a bit tricky.
If you look at the the `ObservableCollection<T>` class:

```
ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

you'll notice that it extends `Collection<T>` and it implements 2 interfaces.

Therefore, since every `Collection<T>` is also a non-generic `IEnumerable` you could reason about the dynamically known ObservableCollection like so:

```
object someObject = ...
bool itsAnObservableCollection = IsObservableCollection(someObject);

if (itsAnObservableCollection) {
    IEnumerable elements = someObject as IEnumerable;
    // and try to reason about the elements in this manner
    foreach (var element in elements) { ... }

    INotifyCollectionChanged asCC = someObject as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    INotifyPropertyChanged asPC = someObject as INotifyPropertyChanged;
    // and try to let yourself receive notifications in this manner
    asCC.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => {
        var newItems = e.NewItems;
        var oldItems = e.OldItems; 
        ...
    };     
    asPC.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
        var propertyName = e.PropertyName;
        ...
    };   

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I was looking for the this. :)
Please tell me how can I find the count of this collection after finding that the object is a collection.

Comment: Please figure out for yourself how you can get the `Count` out of something which is all of these things: `Collection<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `ICollection`, `IList<T>`, `IList`, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`. You can do it in at least 2 ways (which have different costs): the LINQy way and the good ol' .NET 2.0 way.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you need it for, you can also check if it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

```
if (someCollection is INotifyCollectionChanged observable)
    observable.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the collection is generic, you want to test the type's generic definition:

```
collection.GetType()
  .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
  .Equals(typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
```

Comment: That will fail `InvalidOperationException` in most of the times it should've actually returned `false` (ie for instances of non generic types).